# Ordenar ascendentemente en R y SAS

Tags: r, data, sas

Estoy escribiendo en R un script que anteriormente tenía en SAS y me doy cuenta que R ordena de diferente manera. La salida con R, usando

`output<-df[order(df$ID),]` o `output = dplyr::arrange(output, ID,)` es del tipo

```
H0FR640015000399_1CCC   
H0FR640015000399_10CC  
H0FR640015000399_100C 
H0FR640015000399_101C 
H0FR640015000399_102C 
H0FR640015000399_103C 
H0FR640015000399_104C
```

Mientras que con SAS es

```
H0FR640015000399_100C
H0FR640015000399_101C
H0FR640015000399_102C 
H0FR640015000399_103C 
H0FR640015000399_104C
H0FR640015000399_10CC
H0FR640015000399_1CCC
```

Hay alguna manera de hacer que la salida de R sea la misma que consigo con SAS? Me veo obligada a hacer todo con R pero este pequeño percance ya me fastidia todo.

Comment: Me parece que lo que te ocurre es que `df$ID` es un `factor` y no una cadena, de ahí que orden sea distinto. Prueba antes de ordenar, reconvertir la columna con `df$ID <- as.character(df$ID)` y cualquier cosa me comentas. Saludos.

Comment: Ese paso de pasarlo a cadena ya lo había hecho y nada, no el problema persiste. :)

Comment: Es raro, he probado tu ejemplo con cadenas puras y el orden es exactamente igual al que indicas en el ejemplo de SAS. Con `df[order(as.character(df$ID)),]` como funciona?

Comment: Nada, haciéndolo como dices me sigue saliendo igual. Lo que pasa es que los datos sobre los que quiero aplicar el order provienen de una cadena de comandos, ya que estoy adaptando un archivo a un formato determinado para que pueda usarse en otros programas.Lo que acaba de funcionarme es exportar los datos sin ordenar, luego abrir otro script, importarlos y ordenarlos. Es raro, verdad?

Comment: Absolutamente raro. Si quieres una respuesta, deberías compartir la salida de: `dput(df)` como para que lo analicemos. Saludos.

Comment: Hola @Caro puedes intentar con `nv<-as.vector(df$ID)`; `nv<-nv[order(as.character(nv), nv)]`; he imprimirlo por línea con: `cat(nv, sep = "\n")`

Answer (score 0):

Tomé algunos datos de esta [consulta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/234442/c%C3%B3mo-escribir-muchos-ifelse-de-una-mejor-manera) también. Y apliqué el siguiente código que puedes ejecutarlo en [replit](https://repl.it/repls/SilentRadiantRegisters)

```
df <- data.frame(
      "ID" = c("H0FR640015000399_1CCC",   
      "H0FR640015000399_10CC",  
      "H0FR640015000399_100C", 
      "H0FR640015000399_101C", 
      "H0FR640015000399_102C", 
      "H0FR640015000399_103C", 
      "H0FR640015000399_104C" ),

      "año" = c("2005","2007","2010","2012","2013","2016","2018")
)

print(df); cat("\n")

df <- df[order(df$ID),]
print(df); cat("\n")

## Sigue df$ID siendo factor
for(output in df$ID) print(output)

## Se imprime del bucle for
#[1] "H0FR640015000399_100C"
#[1] "H0FR640015000399_101C"
#[1] "H0FR640015000399_102C"
#[1] "H0FR640015000399_103C"
#[1] "H0FR640015000399_104C"
#[1] "H0FR640015000399_10CC"
#[1] "H0FR640015000399_1CCC"

## Cuando es factor nos das las posiciones
cat("\n"); print(c(df$ID))

## Se imprime:
#[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7

## out es ahora un vector
out <- as.character(df$ID)
cat("\n"); print(out)

## Se imprime el vector "out"
#[1] "H0FR640015000399_100C" "H0FR640015000399_101C" "H0FR640015000399_102C"
#[4] "H0FR640015000399_103C" "H0FR640015000399_104C" "H0FR640015000399_10CC"
#[7] "H0FR640015000399_1CCC"
```

Sólo como han mencionado tienes que tener cuidado cuando la columna esté representada como factor y requieras trabajarla después como un vector.