# Cómo escribir muchos ifelse de una mejor manera?

Tags: r, funciones, bucle-for, condiciones

Debo construir una nueva variable usando condicionales, pero tengo tantas condiciones que es una locura controlar lo que escribo y por supuesto, lo que me falla. Aquí un breve ejemplo:

```
df1<-("ind"=c("H0ES1400NA970173", "H0ES1500SS199781", "H0ES1400NA081997", "M0FR640170910243", "M0FR640798940184"),
"padre"=c("0000000000000000","FR640015930519","0000000000000000","ES1500SS950014","ES1500SS950234"),
"madre"=c("0000000000000000","0000000000000000","TR640015930519","FR640015948625","ES1500SS950854"),
"año" =c("2005","2010","2012","2013","2016")
```

Por un lado debo agrupar a los `ind` que contengan `FR` como `grupo1` y `ES` como `grupo2`, lo cual lo he hecho así:

```
df$n1<-ifelse(grepl("FR",df$ind),paste0("GRUPO1",aa$n1),paste0("GRUPO2",aa$n1))
```

Ahora, debo crear una nueva variable que cumpla las siguientes condiciones:

```
df$p1<-ifelse(df$padre=="0000000000000000"&df$madre=="0000000000000000"&df$año<=2005
              ,paste0(df$n1,"050",df$p1),

ifelse(aa$padre=="0000000000000000"&aa$madre!="0000000000000000"
                     ,paste0(df$n1,"P05",df$p1),
                     ifelse(df$padre!="0000000000000000"&df$madre!="0000000000000000"
                            ,df$padre,
                            ifelse(df$padre!="0000000000000000"&df$madre=="0000000000000000"
                                   ,df$padre, "NOT")
```

El tema es que con mi df real tengo que una serie temporal de 20 sobre los que debo poner esa condición de `df$año<=X`, con lo cual tendría que repetir estos 4 ifelse 80 veces. No es que no me funcione, pero es una locura controlar tantos paréntesis y demás. He pensado hacer un bucle for que lea todas filas de todas las columnas y luego poner los condicionales dentro, pero no sé como escribir las condiciones dentro del bucle y luego no entiendo tampoco cómo escribir la salida en una matriz o un data.frame. Por otro lado creo que igual se puede hacer algún tipo de función que teste las diferentes condiciones, pero tampoco tengo muy claro cómo escribirla, cómo anidar los condicionales y luego cómo obtener mi df final. Me pueden ayudar, por favor?

Comment: ¿Cual es el sentido de la condición `df$año<=año` si, según dices debes repetirla varias veces? Por ejemplo, `df$año<=2005`  ya incluiría por ejemplo a `df$año<=2001` .

Comment: Tengo una serie temporal bastante larga y debo hacer los intervalos de tiempo cada 3 años, con lo cual una vez sería <=1990 por ejmplo, luego <=1993 etc.

Comment: Ok, pero `<=1993` también incluye a `<=1990`, no me queda claro el sentido de esa condición.

Comment: A lo mejor no me he explicado bien. Primero debo agrupar los individuos que contienen ES o FR (Y en algún caso otras letras) en grupos diferentes(Grupo1 y 2(En grupo2 siempre sólo ES). Luego debo probar las condiciones de padre y madre que describí y poner "P" o "0" según corresponda (De esta manera iría escribiendo Grupo1P-Grupo10). Luego, debo poner a esa P y ese 0 el intervalo temporal. Por ej, grupo2P03 significa que esos ind son ES, les falta sólo el padre y tienen un año (de nacimiento) que está entre el año 2000 al 2003. También tendré gruposP06, P09 etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En este caso lo recomendable siempre es trabajar los parámetros como vectores para luego aplicar un loop -por ejemplo "for"- sobre ellos.

Generalizando el caso de los grupos como etiquetas de la columna "ind"

```
# Definimos los parametros
grupos = c("GRUPO1","GRUPO2")
etiquetas = c("FR","ES")
b <- as.character(df1$ind) # se aplica coercion

# si longitud grupos es igual a longitud etiquetas
for (i in 1:length(grupos)){
      b[grepl(etiquetas[i],b)] <- grupos[i]
}

df1$ind <- b  # Sobre escribimos
print(df1)

df2$grupos <- b # o Insertamos y organizamos las columnas
df2 <- subset(df2, select=c("ind","grupos","padre","madre","año"))
print(df2)
```

Una de las cosas también que se tiene que tener en cuenta cuando trabajas con data.frame son las columnas en este caso se han definido como factores `print(str(df1))` Por lo tanto años debemos convertirlo en número para evaluar la expresión `df$año<=X` que necesitas

```
df$año <- as.numeric(as.character(df$año)) # se aplica coercion porque 2005 es número
anllos <- df$año
print(anllos)
```

También para simplificar duplique la tabla aa de la original y con esto emplee el siguiente loop

```
for(i in 1:length(anllos)){
df[,paste0("p",i)] <-ifelse(
  df$padre=="0000000000000000"&df$madre=="0000000000000000"&df$año<=anllos[i],
      paste0(df$n1,"050",df$p1),

      ifelse(
        aa$padre=="0000000000000000"&aa$madre!="0000000000000000",
        paste0(df$n1,"P05",df$p1), 

        ifelse(
          df$padre!="0000000000000000"&df$madre!="0000000000000000" ,
          df$padre,

          ifelse(df$padre!="0000000000000000"&df$madre=="0000000000000000" ,
          df$padre, 
          "NOT")
          )
      )
)
}

print(df)
```

Puedes ver el código completo y ejecutarlo en este enlance de [replit](https://repl.it/repls/BadWrathfulServerapplication)

Comment: Gracias, funciona, pero no entiendo muy bien que hace este bucle... for (i in 1:length(grupos)){
  b[grepl(etiquetas[i],b)] <- grupos[i]
} y si en etiquetas tuviera más, a parte de FR y ES? Ese bucle ya no funcionaría, verdad?

Comment: @Caro, el bucle cuando i es 1 la expresión grepl(etiquetas[i],b) te devuelve un vector: FFFVV con lo cual la posición 4 y 5 serán GRUPO1 y similar cuando i=2: VVVFF posición 1,2,3 serán GRUPO2

Comment: Y efectivamente si tuvieras más etiquetas no podrías usar lo anterior porque está pensado para una relación de uno a uno, quizás si quisieras vincular departamentos con ciudades (relación de uno a muchos) igual son datos de entrada, por tanto tocaría repetir cada departamento de acuerdo a la cantidad de ciudades que tenga, como si fuera una tabla y aplicar el bucle for antes señalado.